# reverse string in php server-client

Tags: php

I'm new in php and I'm trying to reverse a string given by a client in a socket connection but it prints 0 instead of the reverse string and I don't know where should I modify to work fine.I put here only the server code before here I do all the things:

```
 >?php
 $sfd = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
 socket_bind($sfd,"localhost",8888);
 socket_listen($sfd,0);
 socket_recv($cfd,$buffer,15,0);
 (string) $sum="";
 for ($i=strlen($buffer)-1; $i>0; $i--){
        (string)$sum=(string)($sum + $buffer[$i]);
 }
 echo "received ".$buffer;
 echo "\n".(string)$sum;
 socket_send($cfd,$sum,9,0)
?>
```

Any ideas?Thank you.

Comment: Your opening tag is bad: >?php

Comment: This is not the problem, but why are you not using `strrev('reverse_me');`?

Comment: I'm receiving a string from a client and I don't know what I receive but I've tried to use strrev($buffer) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $sfd = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
 socket_bind($sfd,"localhost",8888);
 socket_listen($sfd,0);
 socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL)
 echo "received ".$buffer;
 $revStr=strrev($buffer);
?>
```

Use `socket_recv($socket, $buf, 2048, MSG_WAITALL)` method to read all the content from the socket, and then use `strrev($buffer)` to reverse the given string.